# How to fix Fragment Injection vulnerability

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, preferenceactivity

> **Actually this is not my question but I just shared this for information**

How to fix Fragment Injection vulnerability?

Read my own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Actually this is not my question but I just shared this for information**

This information is intended for developers with app(s) using unsafe implementation of PreferenceActivity classes that make them susceptible to Fragment Injection. Such implementation can allow a malicious external app to load Fragments that should be private.

You can visit below link for solutions

> https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188427?hl=en